# How to access an array from stdClass Object (json output) using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json

Hello guys just need a little help here. Because I have a json data and I decode it. But I can't access it using the foreach loop. When I tried to print the array structure I got this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [code] => AD
            [country] => Andorra
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [code] => AE
            [country] => United Arab Emirates
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [code] => AF
            [country] => Afghanistan
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [code] => AG
            [country] => Antigua and Barbuda
        )

    .
    .
    .
```

All I want is to access the code and country

I used this loop but it display the index name and the values:

```
foreach($decode_country as $p){
   foreach($p as $key => $value){
      echo $key."--".$value."<br />";
   }
}
```

But it display:

```
code--AD
country--Andorra
code--AE
country--United Arab Emirates
code--AF
country--Afghanistan
code--AG
country--Antigua and Barbuda
code--AI
country--Anguilla
code--AL
country--Albania
code--AM
country--Armenia
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like

```
foreach($decode_country as $p){
   echo "code -- ".$p->code."<br>";
   echo "country -- ".$p->country."<br>";
}
```

Here `$p` will be considered as an object and you can extract the `code` and `country` using `$p->code` and `$p->country`.Or **Better :** while **decoding** json data you need to give like

```
$decode_country = json_decode($data,true);
```

`true` will return the **array** result.Then use

```
foreach($decode_country as $p){
   echo "code -- ".$p['code']."<br>";
   echo "country -- ".$p['country']."<br>";
}
```

Comment: I also included the boolean TRUE in my decoding but same effect. I got
 Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
foreach($decode_country as $p){
    echo $p->code;
    echo $p->country;
}
```

Here `$decode_country` is an `array` of objects and inside `foreach` loop, each `$p` is an object.

If you use `json_decode($data, true);` then use

```
echo $p['code'];
```

When `TRUE` is used, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.
Otherwise, use

```
echo $p->code;
```

Comment: That's weired, `var_dump($decode_country[0])` should print first object in the array, try this.

Comment: When I var_dump it. It results to:

array(2) {
  ["code"]=>
  string(2) "AD"
  ["country"]=>
  string(7) "Andorra"
}

Comment: Can you show more code with `json_decode` ? Use `json_decode($data);` because you are using `object notation`.

Comment: You mean the json result before decoding it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41939/discussion-between-jerielle-and-rcv)

Comment: Ok I got an answer from Gautam3164. Thanks for the suggestions. :)

Comment: @Jerielle, I've already answered it too, anyways, glad it solved.